# Using Machbase through the Julia ccall function

Tags: database, julia

Using the Machbase DBMS in Julia requires a complicated process. This is because Machbase provides CLI, ODBC, Python connectors, and so on, but does not provide Julia connectors. So I think I need to call the CLI functions of Machbase into Julia's `ccall`. To speed up Machbase properly, you need to use the CLI function. Here's a question:

1. Does the built-in `ccall` function in Julia mean that there is a C language somewhere in Julia folder? If so, how do I include the CLI functions in Machbase into the C language library?
2. To use Julia `ccall`, do you also need to know the name of the library to which the c language function belongs?
3. If so, how do I know the library name of the Machbase CLI function?

Here is Julia's documents.
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/

Here is Machbase's documents.
http://endoc.machbase.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3178831